# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unsupported pseudo

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector

I am trying to fix a bug in my code which is very weird. I have the following code that creates an HTML. It calls a `RemoveCompareOffer()` function upon clicking a div. This function works fine for all types of `id` except for one id which is `ADSL2:Bundles`

Function that creates HTML:

```
function AddCompareOfferInCompareBox()
{
    $('.SelectedOffer').each(function () {
        innerHtml = innerHtml + '<div class="compare-box"> <div class="compare-close"><span class="closed" onclick="RemoveCompareOffer(\''+ $(this).attr("id") + '\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></div>'
             + '<div class="compare-logo"><img src="' + $(this).attr("imagelink") + '" /></div><p>' + $(this).attr("offername") + '</p>'
             + '<input type="button" value="View Details" class="viewbtn" onclick="CallOfferRenderAction(\'' + $(this).attr("offercode") + '\',\'' + $(this).attr("providercode") + '\')" /></div>';
    });

    $(".AddCompareOfferByMe").html(innerHtml);
}
```

On this Function when it is called like this `RemoveCompareOffer('ADSL2:Bundles')`

```
function RemoveCompareOffer(id) {
    $('#' + id + '.SelectedOffer').removeClass("SelectedOffer").addClass("NotSelected").attr('checked', false);
    AddCompareOfferInCompareBox();
    SetCompareBoxsState();
}
```

It Throws error:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:3 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized
>   expression: unsupported pseudo: Bundles

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#ADSL2:Bundles.SelectedOffer` is a selector saying to find the element that:

- Has the `id` `ADSL2`
- Matches the pseudo-class `:Bundles`
- Has the class `SelectedOffer`

There's no CSS pseudo-class `:Bundles` nor does jQuery add its own; in your case, it's part of the ID. So you have to either escape the `:` or use attribute matching syntax.

Escaping:

```js
var id = "ADSL2:Bundles";
$('#' + id.replace(/:/g, "\\:") + '.SelectedOffer').css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div id="ADSL2:Bundles" class="SelectedOffer">Escaping</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using attribute matching syntax:

```js
var id = "ADSL2:Bundles";
$('[id="' + id + '"].SelectedOffer').css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div id="ADSL2:Bundles" class="SelectedOffer">Escaping</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you for explaining the whole issue with such clarity! Thumbs up!